# Make pure phthalocyanines from phthalocyanine dyes

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, purification, organometallic-compounds

We need a pure copper phthalocyanine for our experiments. Of course, we can buy it from Sigma Aldrich, but this means we'll have to wait a while. In local area we can buy only dyes which are about 98% purity, which is not enough. Is there any fast and easy method to purify it in lab?

Comment: Did you consider sublimation in vacuum? This article: [*Journal of Materials Science*, **1982**, *17*, 2781-2791](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00644652) might give some directions.

Comment: We have no vacuum equipment in our lab.

Comment: Purifying phthalocyanines is a pain because even the substituted ones aren't very soluble in common solvents (e.g., for chromatography or recrystallization). I *highly* recommend sublimation. You don't need high vacuum. Do you have *any* way to provide reduced pressure?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have any vacuum equipment. But we have a furnace (not designed for vacuum).

Comment: I doubt You will get some higher purity from Sigma Aldrich. Do they garantee some purity?

Comment: Don't know. On the site it is written that "99%" and "sublimed grade", but vhat are the digits after comma is unknown. There are papers where this product was used.